# MySQL-Can we use range for text which has numbers?

Tags: mysql, sql

In the table 'DailyStatus' one the column value text is like 'taskRead2017ww23.3','taskWrite2017ww45.5', etc

That means all the column values has year and work week as string.

How can I get the data if we want as work week ranges.?

For ex. I want all records in the ranges between 2017ww23.3 to 2017ww25.4

I tried with RLIKE and '|' but i need to pass every single work week value to the query like below

```
select * 
  from dailystatus 
 where taskname rlike '.*(*ww23.3 |*ww23.4 | *ww23.3 | .......|25.4 )'
```

The above method seems very difficult if the range increases.

Is there any optimized way to achieve this?

Comment: To **you**, the textual value makes sense. To a computer, it doesn't. Why? Because it's data type is **text** and not something that it can use and perform arithmetic operations related to dates. Is there an optimized way to achieve what you're after? There is - it's called normalization and using correct data types. You're using the database wrong and even if you find a solution, it will be a hack at best, not the correct way to perform tasks.

Comment: @Mjh perfect explanation

Comment: @MayankPandeyz - thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you can take the last 10 characters from the string and use that for the comparison:

```
select ds.* 
from dailystatus ds
where right(ds.taskname, 10) between '2017ww23.3' and '2017ww25.4';
```

Comment: @Gordon..It is working like charming..Thanks a lot..One more ques can we still use the above query with "2017ww23.3_784640"? that means the end is not fixed length.

Comment: @Nithya . . . No.  The last 10 characters would not all be the same.

Comment: Ya..is there any other way?

Comment: @Nithya . . . Could I suggest that you ask *another* question, with a better set of sample data?  This question strongly suggests that the last 10 characters are what is needed.  If you change this question, it will invalidate this answer, which can draw downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `DATE_FORMAT / STR_TO_DATE` for that:

```
STR_TO_DATE(taskname, "taskRead%Yww%d.%m") BETWEEN '2017-03-23 00:00:00' AND '2017-04-25 23:59:59'
```

But definitely, the optimized way would be to instantiate a date from the field as a separate column.

Comment: Hi..thanks for your post..the value "taskRead" is not always same.It may have regex chr like *,will it work still?

Comment: @Nithya, it can be used `REGEXP` instead of a simple text representation or `STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(taskname, '',  8), "%Yww%d.%m")` if it has a fixed-length prefix

Comment: No results found with above query.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you do it like this:

```
declare @tb table(sam varchar(50))
insert into @tb 


select 'taskRead2017ww23.3' union all
select 'taskRead2017ww23.4' union all
select 'taskRead2017ww23.5' union all
select 'taskRead2017ww23.6' union all
select 'taskRead2017ww23.7'


select CAST(replace(replace(sam,'ww',''),'taskRead','') as numeric(18,2)) from @tb 
where CAST(replace(replace(sam,'ww',''),'taskRead','') as numeric(18,2))>= 201723.3
and CAST(replace(replace(sam,'ww',''),'taskRead','') as numeric(18,2))<= 201723.5
```